# Not able to print dropdown options text in my console

Tags: java, selenium

```
    WebElement AllDeptDropDown = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#search-in-dept"));

    Select s = new Select(AllDeptDropDown); 

    List<WebElement>DrpDownOption = s.getOptions();
    System.out.println("Total All Dropdown otions are - " + DrpDownOption.size());
    for (WebElement i : DrpDownOption) {
        System.out.println("DorpdownOptions Texts are - " +i.getText());

    }
```

Console output:

```
Total All Dropdown otions are - 30
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
DorpdownOptions Texts are - 
PASSED: ShopSite

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Answer (score 0):

Try using getAttribute("text") because getText get the innerHtml which options don't have

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna print all **options** in a **drop down**, then you might wanna use this **code** :

```
            Select s =  new Select(Webelement of select tag);
            List<WebElement> allOptions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath for all options may be a class name"));
            for(WebElement options : allOptions){
                System.out.println(options.getText());
    }
```